# JQuery category filter breaks when a category is more than 2 words

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, filter, categories

I am using Jquery to show project categories and filter the projects by which category is selected.

View the code pen here: https://codepen.io/saintasia/pen/dzqZov

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">All projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Front-end</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Back-end</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testing Testing Testing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="projects">
            <h1 class="heading">All Projects</h1>
            <ul id="gallery">
                <li class="design"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/jjtdL443L4w/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="apps"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/y1yQQmozTBw/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="back-end"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/b18TRXc8UPQ/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="apps design"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/klRB1BB9pV8/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="front-end testing-testing-testing back-end"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/y1yQQmozTBw/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="front-end design"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1vwwZ-BmmrE/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="apps"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/WLOCr03nGr0/700x700"></a></li>
                <li class="back-end"><a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/iOykDIkZLQw/700x700"></a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- modal gallery -->
        <div class="gallery">
            <a class="close" href="#">
                <i>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                </i>
            </a>
            <img src="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow:auto;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #F39CC3;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
   list-style: none; 
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #27A4DD;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #27A4DD;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover, .current a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #27A4DD;
}

#projects > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 23%;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* Padding stays within the width */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#projects > ul > li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.gallery {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 40px 10px;
    display: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery > img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.close i {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.bar:first-child {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    #projects > ul > li {
        width: 48%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 568px) {
    #projects > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// filter
$('nav a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // current class
    $('nav li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    // set new heading
    $('h1.heading').text($(this).text());

    // filter link text
    var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');

    // remove hidden class if "all" is selected
    if(category == 'all-projects'){
        $('ul#gallery li:hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('ul#gallery li').each(function(){
           if(!$(this).hasClass(category)){
               $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
           } else {
               $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
           }
        });
    }
    return false;        
});
// lightbox
$('ul#gallery a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.gallery img').attr('src', '');
    $('.gallery img').attr('src', link);
    $('.gallery').fadeIn('slow');
});
// close lightbox
$('.gallery').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.gallery').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

});

The problem I am having is that if a category is more than 2 words, it doesn't show the projects with that category. You'll see in the code pen that there is a category called "Testing Testing Testing" and one of the projects has that category assigned to it. But, when you click the Testing Testing Testing category, no projects show up. All of the other categories work however, because they are all only 2 words long.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no category called Testing Testing Testing in the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code break because the .replace(' ', '-') code just replace the first space 
if you want to change all space with '-', you should change this code

```
var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
```

to this

```
var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
```